# ROR Controller method "Update" not updating the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I have an update method in my controller as follows:

```
def edit
 @card = Card.find(params[:id])  
end

def update
 @card = Card.find(params[:id])
 if @card.update_attributes(params[card_params])

   flash[:success] = "Changes saved"

   redirect_to new_card_path(:deck =>@card.deck_id)         

 else
    redirect_to new_card_path(:deck =>@card.deck_id)                       
 end

end


private

def card_params
    params.require(:card).permit(:atext, :qtext, :deck_id)
end
```

And my form  is as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for @card, :html => { :method => :put} do |f| %>

<p> Fields marked with * are required </p>

<div><%= f.label "Question *" %> <br />
<%= f.text_area :qtext, :autofocus => true, :default => @card.qtext  %></div>

<div><%= f.label "Answer *" %> <br />
<%= f.text_area :atext, :autofocus => true, :default => @card.atext %></div>

<%= f.hidden_field :deck_id, :value => @card.deck_id %>


<%= f.submit "Save Changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

<%end%>
```

When the form is filled out, it does redirect as if it updated the attributes and the flash[:success] message does in fact appear, but the changes don't actually get stored in the database.

Any suggestions?

In case you're wondering, I'm using "resources: cards" in my routes to gain access to the edit and update methods.

edit*

details of Card model (as requested)

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :deck
    belongs_to :recent_deck
    belongs_to :favorite_deck


    has_one  :deck
    validates :atext, :qtext, presence: true


after_create :do_setID

   private
def do_setID

  newID = self.id
  self.update_attributes(:card_id => newID)
end
   end
```

Comment: Can you add details of "Card" model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `card_params` method returns a hash of attributes and because of that `params[card_params]` is `nil`.

Replace:

```
if @card.update_attributes(params[card_params])
```

with:

```
if @card.update_attributes(card_params)
```

Comment: aha! you're a genious